# Spring wrong number of arguments exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have started working on Spring Boot for a while. For a project, I am trying to use factory bean for datasource creation. Ultimately, i need to create datasources dynamically from another db table. I have a prototype bean that creates a new datasource each time i call context.getBean("getDbEndpointDatasource", args....)

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
@Qualifier("getDbEndpointDatasource")
public DataSource getDbEndpointDatasource(String url, String className, String userName, String password) {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(className);
    dataSource.setUsername(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);

    return dataSource;
}
```

I am getting datasource by using below.

```
DataSource getDbEndpointDatasource = (DataSource) context.getBean("getDbEndpointDatasource",
            "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/spring-test?user=spring-test&password=spring",
            "org.postgresql.Driver", "spring", "spring");
```

So, with the configuration above, i get the below exception when i start spring boot.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
... 103 more
```

I have been searching for a while why spring gives this exception. I also have another factory bean that is prototype scoped as well and it gives me a new object each time it is calld as expected. But here, i don't understand why i get this error. The number of arguments i passed to context.getBean method seems correct. Also, if i remove Scope annotation, i get no exception but it gives me the same datasource each time i call. I am not sure if i miss anything. It seems strange to me.

I appreciate if someone can give a clue or guide.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to create the DataSource yourself, spring-boot does it for you. Just specify the properties in your `application.properties/application.yml`. Also it's not a good idea to create Datasource with scope "prototype"

Comment: I would if i had the connection parameters beforehand. But as i stated in the question, the db parameters will be fetched from the db that is defined in the application.properties. There will be additional db that application will access. So, i need to initialize the db after i start the spring application. Do you have any idea how could i programmatically create datasources then?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like below.

```
DataSource endpointDatasource = (DataSource) context.getBean("getDbEndpointDatasource");
endpointDatasource.getDbEndpointDatasource("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/spring-test?user=spring-test&password=spring","org.postgresql.Driver", "spring", "spring");
```

Comment: ı didn't get this. Datasource class doesn't have an getDbEndpointDatasource method.

Comment: what is the class name for the bean?..DataSource should be replaced with bean name actually.